# Hosting wildcard domains such as *.mydomain.com on Windows Azure without using redirections

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, subdomain, wildcard, azure

I have an ASP.NET MVC app which offers wildcard domains to my users to personalize their login urls.

I'd like to host this on Windows Azure. But is it possible to keep the wildcard domains?

I've already found a [blog article](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CBQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.smarx.com%2Fposts%2Fcustom-domain-names-in-windows-azure&ei=2zBrS5nHB5iJ_Aaf5KG_Bg&usg=AFQjCNGhj1tp_442vk-_QtnQuFL715sf9Q&sig2=d7RyscRnvQu6le-kwu9bxA) showing how to do this with CNAME aliases, but that does not seem to work with wildcard subdomains.

Is there some other way? Preferably one that does not require a redirection for each and every request to the server?

Also, what about the root domain (mydomain.com)?

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that, while DNS standard does not explicitly permit CNAME wildcard entries, it does not forbid them either. So there are actually DNS servers that offer wildcard CNAME entries. Aparently [BIND does](https://serverfault.com/questions/117671/will-a-wildcard-cname-take-precedence-over-a-named-cname-record), for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [blog post](http://www.stratospher.es/blog/post/wildcard-subdomains-in-windows-azure) I put together about doing this with Azure and Route 53 DNS.  It is possible, just not with Go Daddy's DNS.