# Will a wildcard CNAME take precedence over a named CNAME record?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

Generally wondering whether its possible to have both a CNAME entry with a " * " to domain and a seperate subdomain mapping i.e. like

```
*              | CNAME | domain.com
bla.domain.com | CNAME | some.example.com
```

Is this possible or does the * overwrite the "bla.domain.com" and therefore when you enter "bla.domain.com" you go to "domain.com" ?

Answer (score 19):

In BIND, the wildcard matches when another record does not exist.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record.

Comment: Not just BIND, any RFC 1912 DNS server will do this.

Comment: RFC1912 is telling _operators_ how not to do wildcards.  RFC 1035 is the one that _servers_ comply with.

Answer (score 14):

A more specific entry always overrides a wildcard, not the other way around.

For chapter and verse, see §4.3.3 of [RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034).

Comment: From the very last paragraph of section 4.3.3: "For example, if a wildcard
     RR has an owner name of \*.X, and the zone also contains RRs
     attached to B.X, the wildcards would apply to queries for name
     Z.X (presuming there is no explicit information for Z.X), but
     not to B.X, A.B.X, or X."